# Partitioning a Set: Need help with Notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, set-partition

If I have a relation: $$R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : \cos(x)=\cos(y)\},$$
it is clear to me that $[x]= \{x,-x : x \in \mathbb R\}$

What I'm trying to say is that the equivalence class $x$ is partitioned into the set of all $x$ with $-x$.
It is clear because of course $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ OR $\cos(x)=\cos(x)$, and of course $\cos(x)$ is defined for all real numbers.

I am just unsure of how this would be written correctly.
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: Also if I may add, I understand that x=y (mod 2pi) , where y is an element of the reals.. but I'm unsure if that is necessary to specify, or how would that be written:
P={{x,-x} : x=y mod(2pi) st y element of Reals} is what would make logical sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write that the equivalence class of $x$ consists of $x$ and $-x$ is to say $[x]=\{x,-x\}$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  However, as noted in thanasisddr's answer, the equivalence class of $x$ actually consists of elements of the form $\pm x+2k\pi$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  You can write this as $$[x]=\{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{-x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$

If you want to write the entire partition as a set, it would then be $P=\{[x]:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, where $[x]$ is defined as above, or more directly $$P=\{\{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{-x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}:x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
That is, $P$ is the set of all expressions of the form $\{x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{-x+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $x$ can be any element of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK thank you, I see what you are saying, where instead of an intersection where the set consists of x and -x, the correct way is the union of each. (I presume).